# Sidekiq worker and arguments size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scalability, sidekiq

Currently I've this code in one of my Sidekiq worker :

```
def perform(identity_id, format, model, items_ids, columns, options)
  ExportListService::Dispatcher.new(
    identity: identity_from(identity_id),
    format:   format,
    items:    items_from(model, items_ids),
    columns:  columns,
    options:  options&.symbolize_keys! || {}
  ).perform
end
```

The `items_from` method is in charge of recovering each item from the database in the order it was sent within the array `items_ids`, then we proceed through the service.

The order is very important as the controller which initiate this worker has multiple filters and options, IDs can be sent in all kind of orders which should not be lost when transmitted to Sidekiq.

Works great, but I realised this `items_ids` array could have **more than 5 000 entries in it.**

In term of scalability, what would be best ?

- Keep it as it is, it won't impact the worker performance if the array is big. I didn't find anything relevant to params length about Sidekiq, so I don't know if it'll break the performances.

OR

- Take the whole controller logic to sort this `items_ids` and copy it into the worker (imply possible duplicate and hard to maintain code)

What solution should I take ? Is there any other possibility I didn't think of ?

Comment: Data size of job arguments does impact performance, of course, because the arguments are sent to/from redis (this naturally implies serialization/deserialization). If your jobs have payload of 10KB or more, you'll get significantly lower throughput, compared to 20 byte payload. Use this info (and results of your own benchmarks) to make a sufficiently informed decision.

Comment: Looking at your code, it is entirely possible that the cost of marshaling an array of 5k ids will be insignificant compared to the actual work you're doing on them (looks like remote calls). Again, do your own benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid pushing this much data to Sidekiq. We use Sidekiq workers mainly to kick off some async processing, only passing the information required to start the processing.

From your description, I would move the ids sorting logic to the model and query the model from either controller or worker.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I create an ActiveRecord object/table called: XYZJobRequest

Now, this JobRequest entry gets created at some point in the application life cycle. It has all the info in it, or there is reference to the info in it.

When calling Sidekiq all I do is, pass in the ID of the JobRequest object as the only parameter. (Usually with a "on_commit" hook) This keeps things simple.

Would that make sense for you?